# Pygame not responding when Doing calculations

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently working on a AI v AI game in pygame, I am just finishing it but one of the functions doesn't work as expected.
It is something like this (this is in the pygame.event.get() loop):

```
if event.type == right_input:
    for e in range(100):
        data = compute_data(variables)
        re_draw_window(data)
```

The compute_data function can take 0.5 seconds but after something like 30 times the pygame window stops to respond and after 20 seconds when it returns to the event loop it shows the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th issue is causes by the loop in the loop. `compute_data` and `re_draw_window` is executed 100 times in a row. Meanwhile the window does not respond, because the events are not handled. The inner loop blocks the application, till the loop terminates.

Change the setup and initialize a variable `count` before the application loop and increment `count` in the loop.
To start the process once by an input, then add a variable `start` to the application and set the variable in the input event:

```py
start = False
count = 0
while True:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == right_input:
            # start the process
            start = True


    if start:
        # run the process
        if count < 100:
            data = compute_data(varibals)
            re_draw_window(data)
            count += 1
```

Comment: @Shainy_oreng I've changed the answer.